# Integration problem with EFD-REINF 2.01.02

Tags: xml

I am facing an issue when updating our Java system to [*EFD-REINF 2.01.02*](http://sped.rfb.gov.br/pagina/show/7186). The problem seems to be related to the *XML* structure sent to the *EFD-REINF* webservice. Before sending the *XML*, we perform a validation to ensure that the structure is correct, as per the *XLSX* file provided by *EFD-REINF*.

So far, I haven't found a suitable solution to this problem on related forums and websites, as the error messages returned are quite generic.

In summary, after querying the document status protocol at the endpoint https://reinf.receita.economia.gov.br/recepcao/lotes , we receive a response indicating that the file was not sent correctly.

Here is the XML sent to the endpoint:

```xml
<Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/envioLoteEventosAssincrono/v1_00_00">
    <envioLoteEventos>
        <ideContribuinte>
            <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
            <nrInsc>00000000</nrInsc>
        </ideContribuinte>
        <eventos>
            <evento Id="IDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
                <ns2:Reinf
                    xmlns:ns2="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtInfoContribuinte/v2_01_02"
                    xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <ns2:evtInfoContri id="IDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
                        <ns2:ideEvento>
                            <ns2:tpAmb>1</ns2:tpAmb>
                            <ns2:procEmi>1</ns2:procEmi>
                            <ns2:verProc>2.01.02</ns2:verProc>
                        </ns2:ideEvento>
                        <ns2:ideContri>
                            <ns2:tpInsc>1</ns2:tpInsc>
                            <ns2:nrInsc>00000000</ns2:nrInsc>
                        </ns2:ideContri>
                        <ns2:infoContri>
                            <ns2:inclusao>
                                <ns2:idePeriodo>
                                    <ns2:iniValid>2023-10</ns2:iniValid>
                                    <ns2:fimValid>2023-10</ns2:fimValid>
                                </ns2:idePeriodo>
                                <ns2:infoCadastro>
                                    <ns2:classTrib>99</ns2:classTrib>
                                    <ns2:indEscrituracao>0</ns2:indEscrituracao>
                                    <ns2:indDesoneracao>0</ns2:indDesoneracao>
                                    <ns2:indAcordoIsenMulta>0</ns2:indAcordoIsenMulta>
                                    <ns2:indSitPJ>0</ns2:indSitPJ>
                                    <ns2:contato>
                                        <ns2:nmCtt>THAIS XXXXXX</ns2:nmCtt>
                                        <ns2:cpfCtt>00000000000</ns2:cpfCtt>
                                        <ns2:foneFixo>0032000000</ns2:foneFixo>
                                        <ns2:foneCel>0032000000</ns2:foneCel>
                                        <ns2:email>CONTABILIDADE@XXX.COM.BR</ns2:email>
                                    </ns2:contato>
                                    <ns2:softHouse>
                                        <ns2:cnpjSoftHouse>80400000000000</ns2:cnpjSoftHouse>
                                        <ns2:nmRazao>XXXXXX INFORMATICA LTDA</ns2:nmRazao>
                                        <ns2:nmCont>SUPORTE</ns2:nmCont>
                                        <ns2:telefone>0003006611</ns2:telefone>
                                        <ns2:email>suporte@xxx.com.br</ns2:email>
                                    </ns2:softHouse>
                                </ns2:infoCadastro>
                            </ns2:inclusao>
                        </ns2:infoContri>
                    </ns2:evtInfoContri>
                    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <SignedInfo>
                            <CanonicalizationMethod
                                Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                            <SignatureMethod
                                Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                            <Reference URI="#ID18260000000000000000000000001">
                                <Transforms>
                                    <Transform
                                        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                                    <Transform
                                        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                                </Transforms>
                                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                                <DigestValue>zdnff+xXXXXXXXXXXXXA1y8KVXQvTrk436Z8=</DigestValue>
                            </Reference>
                        </SignedInfo>
                        <SignatureValue>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</SignatureValue>
                        <KeyInfo>
                            <X509Data>
                                <X509Certificate>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&#xd;
                                    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&#xd;
                                    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&#xd;
                                    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&#xd;
                                    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&#xd;
                                    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&#xd;
                                </X509Certificate>
                            </X509Data>
                        </KeyInfo>
                    </Signature>
                </ns2:Reinf>
            </evento>
        </eventos>
    </envioLoteEventos>
</Reinf>
```

And here is the XML returned from the protocol consult (https://reinf.receita.economia.gov.br/consulta/lotes/):

```xml
<Reinf
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/retornoLoteEventosAssincrono/v1_00_00">
    <retornoLoteEventosAssincrono>
        <ideContribuinte>
            <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
            <nrInsc>XXXXXXXXX</nrInsc>
        </ideContribuinte>
        <status>
            <cdResposta>3</cdResposta>
            <descResposta>Lote processado com sucesso - Possui um ou mais eventos com ocorrências de
                erro.</descResposta>
        </status>
        <dadosRecepcaoLote>
            <dhRecepcao>2023-10-25T14:58:51.447</dhRecepcao>
            <versaoAplicativoRecepcao>2.0.1-1600512</versaoAplicativoRecepcao>
            <protocoloEnvio>1.202310.0000000</protocoloEnvio>
        </dadosRecepcaoLote>
        <dadosProcessamentoLote>
            <versaoAplicativoProcessamentoLote>2.0.1-1608191</versaoAplicativoProcessamentoLote>
        </dadosProcessamentoLote>
        <retornoEventos>
            <evento Id="IDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX5000001">
                <retornoEvento>
                    <Reinf
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtTotal/v2_01_02">
                        <evtTotal id="IDXXXXXXXXXXXX0294038679">
                            <ideEvento>
                                <perApur />
                            </ideEvento>
                            <ideContri>
                                <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                                <nrInsc>00000000</nrInsc>
                            </ideContri>
                            <ideRecRetorno>
                                <ideStatus>
                                    <cdRetorno>1</cdRetorno>
                                    <descRetorno>ERRO</descRetorno>
                                    <regOcorrs>
                                        <tpOcorr>1</tpOcorr>
                                        <localErroAviso> - Campo: xmlns - XPATH: /Reinf/@xmlns</localErroAviso>
                                        <codResp>MS0055</codResp>
                                        <dscResp>O campo 'xmlns' é obrigatório e não foi informado.</dscResp>
                                    </regOcorrs>
                                    <regOcorrs>
                                        <tpOcorr>1</tpOcorr>
                                        <localErroAviso>Registro: idePeriodo - XPATH:
                                            /Reinf/evtInfoContri/infoContri/inclusao/idePeriodo</localErroAviso>
                                        <codResp>MS1005</codResp>
                                        <dscResp>Já existe outro registro com período conflitante
                                            com o período informado.</dscResp>
                                    </regOcorrs>
                                </ideStatus>
                            </ideRecRetorno>
                            <infoRecEv>
                                <dhRecepcao>2023-10-25T14:58:51.447</dhRecepcao>
                                <dhProcess>2023-10-25T14:58:51.5717635-03:00</dhProcess>
                                <tpEv>1000</tpEv>
                                <idEv>ID1213XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX14584900001</idEv>
                                <hash>1jxSew1pZmXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXyg87jkYn03PqQ2/teE=</hash>
                            </infoRecEv>
                        </evtTotal>
                        <Signature
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                            <SignedInfo>
                                <CanonicalizationMethod
                                    Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                                <SignatureMethod
                                    Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                                <Reference URI="#ID90010000000XXXXXXXXXXXX679">
                                    <Transforms>
                                        <Transform
                                            Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                                        <Transform
                                            Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                                    </Transforms>
                                    <DigestMethod
                                        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                                    <DigestValue>989hxPJXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXOcVLUy+N2Q=</DigestValue>
                                </Reference>
                            </SignedInfo>
                            <SignatureValue>
                                F716jvXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXZTQvwtbNp7lnMRj6R2G14biNqOu+zbDwS4LMlActrgy/974u8i0u44VFdrqd3wIaUng+xXx30u+skKyp1OOpc3fOa804RdOPT+4QnxwvVOcW6KrF3FdbU5U4NV9fK8BZYXiH5KGzLdR93uKP1ERpOBErmn+iQv0CbTT6xf5TgTyQLEEv1iheIXfivA2FHKKGw8V1Vns0yQNW3qMp0RO8n3wNNX6RfVZsooA0oZkl41RZGW8Bcc3x2BHH7iQZmYRD62GqZBw==</SignatureValue>
                            <KeyInfo>
                                <X509Data>
                                    <X509Certificate>
                                        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</X509Certificate>
                                </X509Data>
                            </KeyInfo>
                        </Signature>
                    </Reinf>
                </retornoEvento>
            </evento>
            <evento Id="ID121301475XXXXXXXXXXXXXX4585000002">
                <retornoEvento>
                    <Reinf
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtTotal/v2_01_02">
                        <evtTotal id="ID90010XXXXXXXXXX509XXXX9">
                            <ideEvento>
                                <perApur>2023-10</perApur>
                            </ideEvento>
                            <ideContri>
                                <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                                <nrInsc>21XXXXXXXX5</nrInsc>
                            </ideContri>
                            <ideRecRetorno>
                                <ideStatus>
                                    <cdRetorno>1</cdRetorno>
                                    <descRetorno>ERRO</descRetorno>
                                    <regOcorrs>
                                        <tpOcorr>1</tpOcorr>
                                        <localErroAviso> - Campo: xmlns - XPATH: /Reinf/@xmlns</localErroAviso>
                                        <codResp>MS0055</codResp>
                                        <dscResp>O campo 'xmlns' é obrigatório e não foi informado.</dscResp>
                                    </regOcorrs>
                                </ideStatus>
                            </ideRecRetorno>
                            <infoRecEv>
                                <dhRecepcao>2023-10-25T14:58:51.447</dhRecepcao>
                                <dhProcess>2023-10-25T14:58:51.6791257-03:00</dhProcess>
                                <tpEv>2010</tpEv>
                                <idEv>ID1213XXXXXXXXXXX005243</idEv>
                                <hash>+6FSHh5dXXXXXXXXXXXXuFQ5dTIXMu4=</hash>
                            </infoRecEv>
                        </evtTotal>
                        <Signature
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                            <SignedInfo>
                                <CanonicalizationMethod
                                    Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                                <SignatureMethod
                                    Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                                <Reference URI="#ID90010000000XXXXXXXXXXXXX629">
                                    <Transforms>
                                        <Transform
                                            Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                                        <Transform
                                            Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                                    </Transforms>
                                    <DigestMethod
                                        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                                    <DigestValue>xuGXjE61AVyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXv6jU++hlBE/4=</DigestValue>
                                </Reference>
                            </SignedInfo>
                            <SignatureValue>
                                aCr6JEfE18HvGwU2tXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXidFg305X+tCFOXOHPHT2LOP5WF6x/EGARPC5snOKFyaqpt1W0D7pkFyMHOgsB2WJnKnGGjKYW7PgMwUAC7Q/uiOuIhQmSPTTKIK/zQsEkNcf0080Wx9EEaA2o2ezEgTSrrEyxLD/Aq4+WTCTykGhlgBugtUSTcuCzoIqtD4n4c/0lQS4ZB74VJltvwC5iBftfUrJgv82luAuOo9Gt8sqq+e53qYimawA/R1fsAHzHFRKGYhrNA==</SignatureValue>
                            <KeyInfo>
                                <X509Data>
                                    <X509Certificate>
                                        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</X509Certificate>
                                </X509Data>
                            </KeyInfo>
                        </Signature>
                    </Reinf>
                </retornoEvento>
            </evento>
        </retornoEventos>
    </retornoLoteEventosAssincrono>
</Reinf>
```

The error part I need to correct initially would be:

```xml
<localErroAviso> - Campo: xmlns - XPATH: /Reinf/@xmlns</localErroAviso>
<codResp>MS0055</codResp>
<dscResp>O campo 'xmlns' é obrigatório e não foi informado.</dscResp>
```

I would like to know if anyone has encountered this issue before or has any suggestions on how to fix it. All information and tips are greatly appreciated.

I tried to validate the XML file I am sending through other means, but they also did not report any errors.

I attempted to include additional tags to be signed.

I was hoping that when checking the response, no errors would be encountered.

Comment: The message seems to be indicating that the `Reinf` element doesn't have the namespace declared, but it does. Maybe it just doesn't like the namespace that you specified? Double check that it is exactly what it should be?

Comment: @MadsHansen thanks for repply. The "Reinf" element is indeed necessary. If removed, the XML validator will flag an error, and it's not possible to proceed with the code. 

Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: No.  You have a schema that MUST be met.  Bypassing the schema check will cause issues when the xml is used.

Comment: I managed to find the error.
In this part:
```xml
<ns2:Reinf
xmlns:ns2="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtInfoContribuinte/v2_01_02"
xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">```

You can see that there are "ns2" and "ns3" next to "Reinf" and "xmlns."
I just had to remove them, and it worked!